"Unfortunately, there was a problem" error in flow builder
I updated my flow in flow builder and I am now getting this error systematically when executing the "Run asynchronously" branch of my flow:
"Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 1687869639-228943 (-2098362981)"

All I did before getting this error was updating the callout action (assignment of key parameter to another variable than previously):

It's nothing to say that this error message is not giving a lot of clues...
Did you already encounter this type of message? What could be the reason in my case?
Thank you very much for your help!

trying putting the same value in postman and make a callout. It might be the issue from the API

You can also try to run this flow normally not from debugger and look at browser dev tools -> console. There is chance that you will get specific error message there

@user1974566
Solved!I I checked at the (btw very verbous) logs in developper console but didn'tactually find anything suspicious. Then I activated the flow and tested it in real life and everything went fine. So it's just not working in debug but working correctly when activated... Thanks a lot for your help!

@PARAG TALUKA Thanks to you also for proposing Postman to check the API. FYI, I had tried it but Postman was not giving any error (Status 200 OK) but also not giving the expected result (update of issue field in Jira with status 204). In place, it received the definition of issue fields. Strange...

Solved by activating the flow. This one is actually working in real life and giving the error only in debug mode.
